# Symfony2 doctrine:generate:entities throw Syntax Error?

Tags: doctrine, symfony, entities

**when i am using the symfony2 shell and trying to run**

```
doctrine:generate:entities [MyBundle] --path='src'
```

**or**

```
doctrine:generate:entities [MyBundle]
```

**i got this error**

```
[Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACES, got '@' at position 255 in property
```

**so please any solutions ??**

**thanks in advance**

Comment: check the syntax of your annotations?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've encountered this error also. It's just a simple typo in one of your Entity annotations. A quick check of your entities will reveal something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer"              // note the missing close parentheses
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

Taking into account the line number, it's probably somewhere in one of your entity association mappings.

Comment: Just had the problem cause I forgot the closing " before parenthesis. Don't be like me.

Answer (score 8):

Just as cantera says, check the curly braces.

Here are some of symfony annotation errors:

The comma

- Sample Code: @ORM\Column(name="column_name" type="string" length=20 nullable=false)
- Error Message: [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'type' at position 62 in property ...

Using the wrong type

- Sample Code: @ORM\Column(name="column_name", type="string", length="20", nullable=false)
- Error Message: [Type Error] Attribute "length" of @ORM\Column declared on property ...