# I have an error when using API platform SWAGGER on Symfony4 project

Tags: php, api, symfony, swagger, symfony4

I made this for GET statement in the controller

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller\Api;


use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Factory\EntityFactory;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Model;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


class ArticlesController
{
    private $repository;
    private $factory;
    private $serializer;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepository $repository, EntityFactory $entityFactory, SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->factory = $entityFactory;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    /**
     * @Route(path="/articles/{article}", methods={"GET"}, name="article_get")
     *
     * @SWG\Get(
     *     tags={"Articles"},
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *        name="article",
     *        in="path",
     *        type="integer",
     *        description="Article ID",
     *     ),
     * )
     * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Article fetched",
     *     @Model(type=Article::class, groups={"article:get", "article:category", "category:index"})
     * )
     */
    public function get(Article $article): JsonResponse
    {
        $data = $this->serializer->serialize($article, 'json', ['groups' => ['article:get', 'article:category', 'category:index']]);

        return new JsonResponse($data, JsonResponse::HTTP_OK, [], true);
    }

}
```

The entity from the article looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;



/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Article implements EntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"article:id", "article:get", "article:index"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"article:category"})
     *
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"article:create", "article:get", "article:index", "article:update"})
     */
    private $lead;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"article:create", "article:get", "article:index", "article:update"})
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"article:create", "article:get", "article:index", "article:update"})
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"article:create", "article:get", "article:index", "article:update"})
     * @SWG\Property(property="updated_at")
     */
    private $publishedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"article:category"})
     *
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User\User", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"article:user"})
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $articleFilename;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $marking;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $transitionContexts;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLead(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lead;
    }

    public function setLead(string $lead): self
    {
        $this->lead = $lead;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublishedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publishedAt;
    }

    public function setPublishedAt(\DateTimeInterface $publishedAt): self
    {
        $this->publishedAt = $publishedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?User
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(?User $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getArticleFilename(): ?string
    {
        return $this->articleFilename;
    }

    public function setArticleFilename(?string $articleFilename): self
    {
        $this->articleFilename = $articleFilename;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getImagePath()
    {
        return 'images/'.$this->getImageFilename();
    }

    public function getMarking()
    {
        return $this->marking;
    }

    public function setMarking($marking, $context = [])
    {
        $this->marking = $marking;
        $this->transitionContexts[] = [
            'new_marking' => $marking,
            'context' => $context,
            'time' => (new \DateTime())->format('c'),
        ];
    }

    public function getTransitionContexts()
    {
        return $this->transitionContexts;
    }

    public function setTransitionContexts($transitionContexts): self
    {
        $this->transitionContexts = $transitionContexts;
    }
}
```

And when I go to http://localhost/docs I become this error. That my annotations are not enabled or installed. Thank you for your help.

**Error message:**

> Exception thrown when handling an exception
>   (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\LoaderLoadException: [Syntax
>   Error] Expected
>   Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACES, got
>   'article' at position 179 in method
>   App\Controller\Api\ArticlesController::get() in
>   /app/config/routes/../../src/Controller/Api (which is being imported
>   from "/app/config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure annotations are
>   installed and enabled.)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I'm using Symfony4.2  framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 doctrine:generate:entities throw Syntax Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273299/symfony2-doctrinegenerateentities-throw-syntax-error)

Comment: I found a few typos in the Entity and in the Controller. 
But there is still somewhere a typo or something.  I updated the code